Fail to to static export with next build on NextJS
I'm doing a project with NextJS and TailwindCSS, I would like to move it statically to host it on an apache server, but every time I try to do the "next build" command it generates the following errors:

(I don't use useContext in my files .tsx)
next.config:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export'
};

export default nextConfig;

Repository: Github Link

Please provide some more information: package.json, root layout or _app/_document file. I guess you have a library using it like theme or i18n

@grekier I added the link to the repo

For the project in Github, I made 3 changes and it builds:

Add the output: 'export' to next config which is not in the repo
In src/app/page.tsx, change casing in import of the Intro component: import Intro from "@/components/Intro"; (or change the filename to intro.tsx)
In tsconfig, change mode resolution to node from bundler: "moduleResolution": "node", <-- seems to be an issue in splidejs

Result:
$ npm run build    

> portfolio@0.1.0 build
> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.14

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
 ✓ Collecting page data    
 ✓ Generating static pages (4/4)
 ✓ Collecting build traces    
 ✓ Finalizing page optimization    

Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                    29.6 kB         117 kB
└ ○ /_not-found                          875 B          88.2 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all            87.3 kB
  ├ chunks/117-9c48060295ddae61.js       31.7 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-5af6eea51486f846.js  53.7 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)          1.95 kB


○  (Static)  prerendered as static content

